# Targeted counts after groupby over many columns

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
issue     tag1  tag2  tag3
    a     0        0     0
    a     1        0     0
    a     1        0     0
    a     1        1     1
    b     1        1     0
    b     1        0     0 
    b     0        0     0
    b     1        1     0
    c     0        1     0
    c     1        1     0
    c     1        0     0
    c     0        0     0
```

and I need this output:

```
issue    tag1  tag2  tag3
    a       3     1     1
    b       3     2     0
    c       2     2     0
```

I think I'm looking for something that does this but it obviously wrong and gives the error below. I read up on it and understand the axis argument makes no sense in this context but am not sure what to do.

```
df = df.groupby(['issue']).apply(lambda x: x[x==1],axis=1).count().reset_index()


TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
```

Comment: `df.groupby('issue').sum()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df.groupby('issue').sum()` should solve your problems if those columns only contain ones and zeroes.